# Is OSB stiffer in one direction?

Tags: osb

I know that by construction, OSB is anisotropic -- it has different properties in different directions.

So I wonder: Is is this significant? And if so, which direction is the stiffer/stronger one? I'm mostly interested in bending stiffness when loaded.

I'm considering OSB3, 2500x1250x18mm, if that makes a difference. The project is a detachable bed into my MPV car. So the consideration is in which direction to cut the individual pieces from the board as some of them might be quite narrow (70mm width).

Comment: Use a quality plywood - much stronger for the mass.

Comment: If you understand the word "anisotropic" then you should understand   the point of orienting the wood grain at all different angles is to create strength at all different angles.  That is not to say that it is the proper choice for your project.. But that could just be my simple logic. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropy

Comment: @AlaskaMan Yeah, well, the question is the extent of the anisotropy -- whether it does matter...

Comment: @SolarMike Do you have a reference for that? I have always seen information like the one at https://homeguides.sfgate.com/stronger-strand-board-plywood-99195.html saying they're basically equal in load bearing.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Also, as I ask, if there's significant anisotropy, which direction is the stronger one?

Comment: Last reference I had was a 15 pound sledge hitting both types as we knocked part of a wall down. Osb had holes... and think about the length of strands.

Comment: @SolarMike Ah well, but that's quite a specific type of stress :)

Comment: Stress is stress...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. OSB can be laid in any orientation and will have the same strength as long as it begins and ends on a stud/joist. The thickness is what determines its strength, not which way you decide to lay it.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Completely misleading as the OP is "mostly interested in bending stiffness when loaded." The strength axis stamped on the panel must be perpendicular to the supports in that case.

Comment: My mistake. Certainly not trying to mislead. I tried to delete my answer, but I cannot.